# Is there a rigorous definition for what a "complete" theory without "hidden variables" is?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

I find only vague characterizations of what a theory that is complete and without hidden variables is supposed to be. Such as a theory that is complete means that there is no lack of knowledge about an underlying physical reality and hidden variables being unknown physical quantities. Is there a more rigorous way to define the notion of "completeness" of a theory? How exactly are "hidden variables" defined? If there are no such definitions, how would you describe it in more precise terms?

Comment: I am sure that different people mean (at least slightly) different things by the term "hidden variables", and probably a lot of individuals mean (at least slightly) different things on Sunday than they do on Monday.  But for the most part, "hidden variables" seem to refer to physical quantities whose behavior a) predicts everything we can observe (at least in some specified contexts) and b) have probability distributions that satisfy Kolmogorov's axioms.  Of course there can be no such things unless one is willing to believe in other things that make a great many people uncomfortable.

Comment: What is the difference between having a rigorous definition of a theory that can supersede QM, and having that theory itself? How can we answer your question if we stick to the current state of physics, as we are supposed to do on this site?

Answer (score 0):

> define the notion of "completeness" of a theory? How exactly are "hidden variables" defined? If there are no such definitions, how would you describe it in more precise terms?

First let us be clear of what a "theory" means in physics. It is a mathematical **model** that fits existing data and observations and , very important in order to be validated, makes correct predictions for new data and observations.

Mathematics has complete theories starting from axioms and developing into theorems rigorously. The mathematics of calculus and differential equations allow an infinity of possibilities for rigorous solutions. Physics theories impose extra axiomatic statements, called laws, postulates, and tables of constants which pick up from the infinity of solutions those solutions that fit the data and observations, relating abstract numbers to physical units. Look at the [postulates of quantum mechanics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html), how involved and complicated they are . The [elementary particle table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle) is also axiomatic for the current main stream physics standard model.

So "completeness", the final mathematical model, is complicated by all the assumptions that enter  in the theoretical physics model, it is
more a philosophical search, like the [platonic ideal forms](https://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/engl257/classical/platonic%20idealism.htm).

That is why you find "only vague characterizations of what a theory that is complete and without hidden variables is supposed to be." For such a physics theory the postulates should be simple, connecting the physical units to the mathematical model ( example the geometrical algebraic  model) and all the present  complexity of the physics theory should emerge through mathematical calculations. It is  too complex to define.

Comment: "So "completeness", the final mathematical model, is complicated by all the assumptions that enter in the theoretical physics model, it is more a philosophical search, like the platonic ideal forms."

Ok, I understand that there is no unique definition. However, conceptual clarity still escapes me. Because at this point the question arises if the notion of "completeness" only relates to the knowledge of all hidden variables? May a theory still have some elements of incompleteness also if all the hidden variables are known?

Comment: As I wrote, the example of geometry and the algebraic theory that describes it is the simplest example  of a model theory , . It has  axioms ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_geometry#Axioms ) some of which are connected with physical quantities. There are hidden variables when one goes from euclidean to the spherical that describes the surface of the sphere. So in that sense even if we had a Theory Of Everything we know up to now, new observations /situations  would introduce new variables, which we could call "hidden" as far as the TOE we knew up to then.